# How to escape parenthesis in bash rmdir?

Tags: bash, directory, rm

I have a directory that has a name like `10.2 (14C92)` i want to remove using rmdir -rf (to include their content). I do know how to pass a space with `\` but I got the result:

`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('`

So it seems to me that I somehow have to escape the parenthesis from the command. How am I doing this properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\` to escape **any** single character, `(` and `)` included as you already do with spaces.  While it works, it can be cumbersome if you have lots of characters/spaces to escape.

A faster alternative is to use *single quotes* (`'`) to escape **the whole string**, i.e. something like:

```
rm -rf '10.2 (14C92)'
```

Please keep in mind that `'` escape *everything*, so use it with care if you need, for example, variable expansion inside the quotes. That said, using *double quotes* works for escaping spaces and parentheses, also:

```
rm -rf "10.2 (14C92)"
```

Also, based on your question, you try to use `rmdir`. `rmdir` works only for **empty directories** and it doesn't have `-r` and/or `-f` flags:

> NAME
>         rmdir - remove empty directories
>
> SYNOPSIS
>         rmdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>         Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), **if they are empty**.

You'll want to use `rm -rf`.
If `10.2 (14C92)` is indeed empty, a simple

```
rmdir '10.2 (14C92)'
```

would do.

Escaping is done by `bash` itself, so it works for every command. In other words, it's `bash` which decides **what** to pass to the command, based on its own parsing rules, the command then acts on the arguments *after* `bash` has parsed them.

Answer (score 4):

You are already on the right path. You can use the escape character `\` for parenthesis aswell.

```
rm -r 10.2\ \(14C92\)
```

You can also use quoting:

```
rm -r '10.2 (14C92)'
```

Comment: does this also work with rmdir?

Comment: Yes. This is not specific to the program being run, but to your shell!

Comment: thanks that worked for me, now i am finally able to clean up my drive from old system stuff i don't need anymore. I didn't even had enough space for an OS update before

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf 10.2\ \(14C92\)/` - recursively remove this folder `10.2\ \(14C92\)/` and all of its content.